# I want pigments package in packages list of menu bar

Tags: atom-editor

I have installed pigments package in atom ..I can see this package in settings-installed packages.
But how can I see this package in the packages list which is in menu bar.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the author of the Pigments package decided not to add menu items for the commands. However, you can do so yourself using Atom's [Init Script](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/the-init-file/)

> When Atom finishes loading, it will evaluate `init.coffee` in your `~/.atom` directory, giving you a chance to run CoffeeScript code to make customizations.
>
> You can open the `init.coffee` file in an editor from the *Atom > Init Script* menu. This file can also be named `init.js` and contain JavaScript code.

Menu items can be added programmatically using the [MenuManager API](https://flight-manual.atom.io/api/v1.57.0/MenuManager/#instance-add). Here's a simple example for one of Pigment's commands:

```js
atom.menu.add([
  {
    'label': 'Packages',
    'submenu': [
      {
        'label': 'Pigments',
        'submenu': [
          {
            'label': 'Show Palette',
            'command': 'pigments:show-palette'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

Alternatively, you can populate the menu programmatically. The following example is written in JavaScript, so you would either have to rename the init script as described above or convert it to CoffeeScript.

```js
const packageName = 'Pigments';

const registeredCommands = Object.keys(atom.commands.registeredCommands);
const pigmentsCommands = registeredCommands.filter(item => {
  return item.startsWith(`${packageName.toLowerCase()}:`)
});

if (!pigmentsCommands.length) return;

const menuItems = [
  {
    'label': 'Packages',
    'submenu': [
      {
        'label': packageName,
        'submenu': pigmentsCommands.map(command => {
            const [, label] = command.split(':');

            return {
                // TODO: Format the label
                label: label,
                command: command
            }
        })
      }
    ]
  }
];

atom.menu.add(menuItems);
```